# Select from same column but multiples values and number of records with one specific value

Tags: sql, select

```
ID  Customer    Status
1   ABC 1
2   ABC 2
3   ABC 3
4   ABC 1
5   PQR 1
6   PQR 2
7   PQR 3
8   XYZ 1
9   XYZ 3
```

I want to select customer who has both values "status=1" and "Status=2' and also total number of entry of same customer with Status=1.
So the result  will be,

```
Customer   totalEntryStatus1
ABC        2
PQR        1
```

How can I do this.

Thankyou !

[image: 1]

Comment: also tag dbms you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Customer, count(case when status = 1 then 1 end) totalEntryStatus1
from table
where Status in (1,2)
group by Customer 
having count(distinct Status) = 2
```